# Partial differential equation - DSolve gives no output, but solution exists

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have trouble obtaining solution for equation using DSolve:

[image]

My mathematica code is given by:

`DSolve[\[Kappa]^2  *T + (1/2)*f[G, T] - (1/2) G *D[f[G, T], G] + 
   T* D[f[G, T], T] - (2/(n - 1))*G ^2 D[D[f[G, T], G], G] - 
   3 n^2 (T/\[Rho]0)^(2/3 n) - (3 n)/(2 (n - 1))*G *
    T D[D[f[G, T], T], G] == 0, f[G, T], {G, T}]`

Using this lines gives me no output (output is exactly my dsolve command) - from what i found on stackexchange it means that exact solution doesn't exist. Hoverver solution for this equation is given by:
[image]
where $d_i$ are integration constants and $\chi_i$ are some combinations of $d$'s, $n,\rho_0 $ and $  \kappa$

How to solve this equation with DSolve command? Is there any mathematical trick to manipulate this equation?

Article
[ https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-016-4502-1 ]  where this equation is given and solved doesn't gives any additional information about behaviour of function $f(G,T)$ or any additional equations
- exept that the $n>0$

Answer (score 1):

```
p[t_] := Refine[(po* t^(-3 n)), Assumptions -> n > 0];
G[t_] := Refine[(24*n^3/t^4)*(n - 1), Assumptions -> n > 0];
T[t_] := Refine[(p[t]), Assumptions -> n > 0];



eq = Refine[
  k^2*T[t] + (1/2)*f[G[t], T[t]] - (1/2)*G[t]*D[f[G[t], T[t]], G] + 
   T[t]*D[f[G[t], T[t]], T[t]] - (2/(n - 1))*
    G[t]^2 D[f[G[t], T[t]], {G[t], 2}] - 
   3 n^2 (T[t]/po)^(2/3 n) - (3 n/(2 (n - 1)))*G[t]*T[t] *
    D[D[f[G[t], T[t]], {T[t], 1}], {G[t], 1}], 
  Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals, po \[Element] Reals, n > 0, 
    G[t] \[Element] Reals, T[t] \[Element] Reals, 
    f[G[t], T[t]] \[Element] Reals, t > 0}]



s1 = DSolve[{eq == 0}, f[G[t], T[t]], {G[t], T[t]}] /. Rule -> Equal
```

Comment: You cannot solve PDE in this way. I mean, this won't give anything helpful when solving PDE, AFAIK. Just consider the simplest example: `{DSolve[3 D[y[x1, x2], x1] + 5 D[y[x1, x2], x2] == x1 , y[x1, x2], {x2}],
 DSolve[3 D[y[x1, x2], x1] + 5 D[y[x1, x2], x2] == x1 , y[x1, x2], {x1}]}`.

Comment: i looked up the article so i will edit this answer

Comment: you need to notice and define your G & T because they depend on time and they cancel some terms in the PDE,
My problem i don't know how to define a function F with variable T&G that depend on function T&G with another variable t time!

Comment: So problem is with definitions? $G,T$ arent independent variables so i have to define them as functions dependent on $t$ and then, i have to solve it w.r.t $T$ and $G$?

Comment: i think so that's it

Comment: look up my try after i looked the article

Comment: Now there are messages with 'po\ t^(-3\n) is not a valid variable' and 'Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.'. It's interesting how to implement this  - i believe solving  with respect to $t$won't be correct. Shouldn't it be functional DE  where variables are functions?.

Comment: So, i found paper with simillar calculations  - authors state that this is 2nd order pde with solution. Also for this case mathematica's dsolve return input in output . 
    https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepjc%2Fs10052-016-4104-y